# Converting pandas valuecounts to a specific type

Tags: pandas

I am trying to dispaly the percentages of a particular dataframe column as the percentage of it's grand total. I do have a constraint of this being a specific data type (numpy float does not fly)

My code is quite simple

```
dict(df['marital_status'].value_counts().transform(lambda x: x/sum(x)))
```

I tried `astype()` and trying to cast the values within the transform function itself but no joy.

Comment: Can you show wrong and correct ouput?

Answer (score 2):

Instead your function use `normalize=True` in [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), then for percentages multiple 100 and if need integers after round casting:

```
print (df)
   marital_status
0               1
1               0
2               1
3               1
4               1
5               0
6               0

d = df['marital_status'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).round().astype(int).to_dict()
print (d)
{1: 57, 0: 43}
```